# Drawing Lines Connecting two Gridview Rows

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have no idea if this is possible or not but what I want to do is somehow draw lines between two rows showing that these rows are linked together. The picture below you can see one-row links to another row and I drew a line in paint to represent what I would like to do programmatically.

Is there a way to do this?

If not, are there any suggestions on how to show that two rows are linked that would be visually appealing?

Also, the rows being linked are not alway next to each other, but would like them to be next to one another upon linking in the future.

Thanks a lot for any help.

[image]

Comment: I have been messing around with enabling buttons as black lines in the right column but it is not turning out well. Still searching on what I can do.

Answer (score 0):

Never done this but i have an idea regarding this , a lot of stuff on internet , here my search 
**Javascript** : Get two cordinates first using below function , it will be point of upper left corner  of the controls , you can save them in hidden flag or a select list to use them in c#

```
 var X = obj.offsetLeft;
        var Y = obj.offsetTop;
        while(obj.offsetParent)
        {
            X=X+obj.offsetParent.offsetLeft;
            Y=Y+obj.offsetParent.offsetTop;
            if(obj==document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0])
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                obj=obj.offsetParent;
            }
        }
```

**c#**: Use DrawLine Method

```
   Pen redPen = new Pen(Color.Red, 1);
   System.Windows.Forms.Graphics.DrawLine(redPen , X1, Y1, X2, Y2);
```

I hope meaning of X1,Y1,X2,Y2 is clear here 
It will not a line between center points of controls , but between top left upper corners. But you can adjust that by adding a value to y points to bring it nearby center